# Copy an Alpha numeric number down with numeric number Range

Tags: vb.net, excel

I looking for an easier way to create crate number in Excel without typing them in all the time.

our range starts

```
OLPS1*0001A - OLPS1*0001B - OLPS1*0001C - OLPS1*0001D
```

once it gets to D the next crate will be opened as

```
 OLPS1*0002A - OLPS1*0002B ....
```

What VB code will allow me to create this ranges at ease without having to type them all out?

Comment: I have try coping only the first par in 1 column and the Numbers in the second Column and then the Alpha numeric in the 3rd column. now what I do is = A&B&C. This takes to long

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a VBA solution (not VB.NET). Just try to come up with some code by yourself and post it here when you get stuck.

Comment: Hi @pnuts, it can export in the same sheet just in another column??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt this pattern-maker.  In **A1** enter:

```
="OPS1*" & TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0),"0000") & CHAR(64+MOD(ROW()-1,4)+1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student, Excel is giving me an error "we have found a problem with this formula. Try click on insert...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, in A1 and copied across to suit:

```
="OLPS1*"&TEXT(COLUMN(),"0000")&"A - OLPS1*"&TEXT(COLUMN(),"0000")&"B - OLPS1*"&TEXT(COLUMN(),"0000")&"C - OLPS1*"&TEXT(COLUMN(),"0000")&"D"
```

Comment: HI @pnuts, this also gives me an error 'we have found a problem with this formula. Try click on insert' I must be doing something wrong?